# How I can make a link on my facebook page to redirect to my domain?

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, dns

How I can make a link on my facebook page to redirect to my domain?
I am see an example where it's possible here:[example](https://es-es.facebook.com/thehiptee?v=app_2373072738&filter=2) if you click to button or app that say "Shop Online" it's redirects to the domain.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is done by creating a mini Facebook app whose only contents is a redirect to the domain in question. See [this simple tutorial](http://www.labnol.org/internet/tutorial-write-a-facebook-application/10116/) -- just create a "dummy" HTML page whose only content is:

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://www.yourdomain.com/index.html">
```